# AVERAGIFS equivalent for standard deviation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Is there an equivalent of the AVERAGEIFS function that can give the standard deviation of values in a range selected by a number of criteria?

The AVERAGEIFS syntax I am using is `=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A100;B1:B100;">="&C1;B1:B100;"<="&D1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single function for that, but you can do it with an array formula:

`=STDEV.P(IF((B1:B100>=C1)*(B1:B100<=D1),A1:A100,""))`
This is an array formula, so after entering it press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

(you may need to use STDEV.S instead of STDEV.P depending on your data model)